# Copied/Exported VueJS Project is much smaller than the original

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I did finish my VueJS Applet project the other day and have to send in the code for grading aswell as to the customer.

Now when I copy the folder where the project lies under
.../vue-js-projects/PROJECTNAME
to another place to zip it together with evrerything else the copied file is much smaller.

The original in it's folder is like 200MB whereas the copied one is only about 20MB so 10% the size.

Is this because I'm using an IDE (Webstorm) which creates lot's of local stuff that is not needed when exporting or is there a "right" way to export a vue project.(I'm talking abbut the whole project not just the built ../dist directory)

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Check if you're using shared node_modules folder (outside project folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider version control - github, bitbucket or whatever you like.

.gitignore file will help you to leave unnecessary files locally.

Most of version control platforms offers .zip download, so you dont need to worry about file sizes, some bug fixes, adjustments or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, that seemed to be the issue.